# Dificultar download de vídeo html5

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces, front-end

Gostaria de dificultar o download de vídeos html5 a partir da URL, que o usuário poderá inspecionar (examinar com funções de navegadores). Pesquisando na Net vi que não há uma maneira 100% de não permitir o usuário avançado de fazer download de videos.

Estou utilizando a tag do html5 para exibir vídeos de um curso EAD:

```
<video id="video" 
       src="localhost/path/#{Manegbean.bancoDado.codigo}.mp4" 
       preload="auto" 
       width="780px" 
       height="490px" 
       controls="controls"/>
```

O que consegui fazer até o momento foi desabilitar o `oncontextmenu (false)`, para não permitir a opção de salvar o vídeo pelo navegador, porém se o usuário inspecionar (for um usuário esperto consegue ver os vídeos).

Alguém tem uma dica de como posso esconder bem, a tag que permite visualizar os vídeos?  Se teria esta possibilidade! Se tiver alguma forma de dar mais segurança aos conteúdos será bem vinda.

Obrigado!

Comment: Por favor, não coloque imagem no formato de código. Isso dificulta a leitura e utilização do código para testes.

Comment: Por que colocar uma foto do código ao invés do código diretamente? Isso dificulta a testar e dificulta quem usa leitores de tela (pessoas com algum grau de deficiência visual)

Comment: Sempre podes editar sua pergunta ou resposta, clicando no link [edit], dessa forma você melhora sua postagem e recebe mais atenção da comunidade. Visite [tour] e veja as melhores práticas. Boa Sorte

Answer (score 0):

Existem quatro formas de você prevenir que seus filmes sejam baixados ilegalmente:

- Encriptar seus vídeos para prevenir o download
- Usar uma marca dágua em seus videos para identificar a origem do
  vazamento (e assim permitir um processo judicial)
- Usar uma criptografia DRM
- Usar um DRM Service (como por exemplo o vdocipher)

**O que é DRM?**
O DRM é um controle de acesso a conteúdos digitais, em um conjunto de tecnologias que tem por objetivo proteger conteúdos digitais contra cópias não autorizadas. O objetivo do DRM é assegurar os direitos autorais dos produtores de conteúdo e marcas registradas. A sigla é do inglês: Digital Rights Management (Gestão de Direitos Digitais)

Sites como Netflix, Disney, HBO etc utilizam-se de DRM para impedir que seu conteúdo seja baixado de forma ilegal.

Fonte: https://www.vdocipher.com/blog/prevent-video-download